# Fastlane TestFlight upload primary.test.info missing

Tags: testflight, fastlane

I'm trying to set the `changelog` via Fastlane:

```
changelog = changelog_from_git_commits(
  commits_count: 1)

upload_to_testflight(changelog: changelog)
```

This causes the following error:

> Could not set changeling: {"code"=>"ITC.apps.tf.build.missing.primary.test.info", "description"=>"Missing primary test info."}

This is an app used for internal testing only. I didn't fill in any information on "Test Information" because I don't want to accidentally release it to external testers.

I tried unchecking the following box:

[image]

It still shows the same error message.

What's the minimum amount of information I need to get this to work?

I'm on fastlane 2.108.0. I found some related information [here](https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/issues/8954), but that's mainly with `ITC.apps.tf.build.test.info.missing.whats.new`, which is not the exact error I'm seeing.

Answer (score 0):

Navigate to:

1. [App Store Connect](https://appstoreconnect.apple.com)
2. Choose your App
3. TestFlight
4. Test Information

You will probably see this error message up top:

> ⚠️ Complete test information is required to submit a build for external testing.

You can ignore that. For an internal test to work, you don't need any information on here. However, to get Fastlane's `changelog` feature working, you'll need to fill in the following details...

---

## primary.test.info

> Could not set changeling: {"code"=>"ITC.apps.tf.build.missing.primary.test.info", "description"=>"Missing primary test info."}

You're missing a "beta app description":

[image]

---

## test.info.missing.feedback

> Could not set changelog: {"code"=>"ITC.apps.tf.build.test.info.missing.feedback", "description"=>"Missing feedback email."}

You're missing the "feedback email":

[image]

---

So as a minimum, you need to fill in the following information when using fastlane's TestFlight changelog feature:

1. Beta App Description
2. Feedback Email